# Getting large attachments from facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have no idea how to get full size photos from attachments on my fanpage.

I'm using graph api v2.7, and php sdk 5

```
'/{page_id}/posts?fields=message,attachments,created_time&limit=100
```

That's my GET request, and it returns attachments in specific resolution but I would like to change this one or get full size. Is it possible? I'm confused and tired using this api. Your help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this request:

```
/{page_id}/posts?fields=message,attachments,created_time,full_picture&limit=100
```

Comment: That's not change anything. I get the same size of picture :/ width is max 720px